# How to write test case for faceless-ui/modal modal react jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am writing a test for modal confirmation on button click. I am using faceless-ui/modal the click is working fine but the modal is not opening(Debug the screen no HTML is present for the modal).

```
 <Modal slug='deleteModal' className='delete-document'>
          <MinimalTemplate className='delete-document__template'>
            <h1>Confirm Delete</h1>
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</p>
            <p>{userToDelete && userToDelete.email}</p>
            <Button buttonStyle='secondary' className="modal-button" onClick={() => { deleteUser() }}>Yes</Button>
            <Button buttonStyle='secondary' className="modal-button" onClick={() => { closeModal(modalSlug) }}>Cancel</Button>
          </MinimalTemplate>
        </Modal>
```

```
const mockToggleModal = jest.fn()
jest.mock('@faceless-ui/modal', () => ({
  Modal: jest.fn(),
  useModal: jest.fn(jest.fn(() => ({
    toggleModal: mockToggleModal,
    closeModal: jest.fn(),
  }))),
}));
```

If I am not adding mocking for the modal then getting an error as

```
can not read properties of undefined ('deleteModal')
```

And with mocking Modal is not showing in DOM.

```
 test('click on delete icon and popup open', async () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <CustomDeleteButton rowData={rowData} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
   
    fireEvent.click(container.querySelector('#deleteButton'), new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }));
   
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockToggleModal).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this is working properly
      console.log(prettyDOM())
     
      // expect(screen.getByText('Are you sure you want to delete this user?')).toBeInTheDocument(); // this is not working
    })
  });
```

Note: I tried different approaches like using act, adding delay

I tried different approaches like using act and adding delay. and I am expecting that Modal dom should show up in prettyDOM() or debug

Comment: What's `CustomDeleteButton`? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example